# Sleepwatcher on Ventura

Tags: sleep-wake, homebrew

On macOS Ventura I installed sleepwatcher using homebrew and activated the service using
`brew services start sleepwatcher`. Strange enough it asked for permissions to watch all keystrokes. Ignoring this security issue for now, I granted the permission, but it appears the service is not working. As per the documentation I created bash scripts `.sleep` and `.wakeup` in my home directory, but nothing in these files gets executed. I checked and it looks like the relevant LaunchAgent is correctly placed in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/`

Is anyone successfully running sleepwatcher on macOS Ventura?

Comment: I see that sleepwatcher is running, but it points to paths for the .sleep/.wakeup files: `ps ax |grep sleepw` yields `/opt/homebrew/opt/sleepwatcher/sbin/sleepwatcher -V -s /Users/brew/actions-runner/_work/homebrew-core/homebrew-core/bottles/home/.sleep -w /Users/brew/actions-runner/_work/homebrew-core/homebrew-core/bottles/home/.wakeup`.  But even if I create those files/folders, sleep&watch doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I've added an issue for that here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/126336

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working fine for me - I'm running Ventura 13.6.3 on Apple M2

My config:

```bash
$  sleepwatcher -v
sleepwatcher 2.2.1
Copyright (c) 2002-2019 Bernhard Baehr (bernhard.baehr@gmx.de)
This is free software that comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
See the GNU General Public License for details.

$  ps ax |grep sleepw
 2314   ??  S      0:00.16 /opt/homebrew/opt/sleepwatcher/sbin/sleepwatcher -V -s /Users/admin/.sleep -w /Users/admin/.wakeup
```

I gave execution permissions to both files,

```bash
chmod a+x ~/.sleep
chmod a+x ~/.wakeup
```

checking the service with brew I get

```bash
$  brew services info sleepwatcher
sleepwatcher (homebrew.mxcl.sleepwatcher)
Running: ✔
Loaded: ✔
Schedulable: ✘
User: admin
PID: 2314
```

Lastly, my `.sleep` contains

```bash
#!/bin/bash

networksetup -setairportpower en0 off
```

Then, when I run

```bash
$  pmset sleepnow
Sleeping now...
```

and I re-login, I have my WiFi off